# How to build my own global constraint with the CP-SAT solver of OR-tools?

Tags: data-mining, solver, or-tools, constraint-programming, cp-sat

I am a phd candidate in data mininig, and i have to create a global constraint with ORtools for a data mining purpose.

The problem is that there is a lack of documentation about creating your own global constraint with CP-Sat in the internet, and i don't know how to start.

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible to create your own new custom constraints with OR-Tools SAT Solver. You can do it with the old Google.OrTools.ConstraintSolver, there is an answer under this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48146639/custom-constraint-or-tools-constraint-programming  (which is basically a duplicate of yours...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is obviously possible, but very tedious, and very complex.

Writing a new constraint implies:

- extending the proto to support the constraint
- writing the input validation
- writing the solution checker
- writing the loading (into CP-SAT engine) code
- writing the presolve rules
- writing the propagation code. Which is complex as every deduction needs to be fully explained.
- writing the linearization/cut generation code

The last 3 items are extremely error prone, and very hard to debug, as the effect of cuts and explanations are delayed, and sometimes never used.

For these reason, I recommend expanding the constraint into smaller ones. In fact, most of the CP constraints are expanded (alldiff, element, table, reservoir, inverse, automaton, some products, some modulos).

You can also submit a feature request for a new constraint. It can happen if it is useful/general enough.

Thanks